# Proper way to mosaic a UDP stream with libvlcsharp

Tags: libvlcsharp

Following the Mosaic example [here](https://code.videolan.org/mfkl/libvlcsharp-samples/-/blob/master/VideoMosaic/VideoMosaic/MainPage.xaml) but modified for WPF and changing the url to "udp://@something:1234" only the first video plays.  is there something special i need to do for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaking, that "something" is the listen address, so it is normal that you can't listen twice on the same address

Comment: so maybe the only way would be to have a single mediaPlayer, then i extract the images 1 by 1 and then can pump to multiple views?

Comment: That might be a way to do it, but it's hard. Did you try to use UDP multicast? to use something in the middle that would convert the stream in a RTSP stream?

Comment: Otherwise, if you really want to go the image route, see the thumbnailer example of the API to use, and have a look at Vlc.DotNet's wpf implementation to see how you coud use a WPF image to show your things (your could have multiple images with the same Source, I'm pretty sure). That implementation needs to be translated to LVS though